# How do I read a (garmin) GPX file with PHP

Tags: php, gpx

I found different examples of reading XML with PHP. But could not one get working for me. It's not so difficult to read lan en lon, but I want to read the extensions like temperature too.

Data (from comment)

```
<trkpt lat="30.3248708043" lon="35.4718816280">
    <ele>1051.62</ele>
    <time>2019-10-16T02:53:21Z</time>
    <extensions>
        <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
            <gpxtpx:atemp>24.7</gpxtpx:atemp>
        </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
    </extensions>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="30.3249898273" lon="35.4719382059">
    <ele>1051.62</ele>
    <time>2019-10-16T02:53:45Z</time>
    <extensions>
        <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
            <gpxtpx:atemp>24.4</gpxtpx:atemp>
        </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
    </extensions>
</trkpt>
```

Comment: Can you please include a sample of the data you are trying to read as well as the code you have so far.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500347/gpx-file-parse-with-php-get-extensions-element-values

Comment: <trkpt lat="30.3248708043" lon="35.4718816280"><ele>1051.62</ele><time>2019-10-16T02:53:21Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>24.7</gpxtpx:atemp></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>                                                                                                                          
<trkpt lat="30.3249898273" lon="35.4719382059"><ele>1051.62</ele><time>2019-10-16T02:53:45Z</time><extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:atemp>24.4</gpxtpx:atemp></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions></trkpt>