# read xml nodes in php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read some specific child nodes from xml in php which i want to display but i m not able to display the node values.Following is my xml format which i m trying to read

```
<nns2:ApiDirectory xmlns:ns2="https://sourceurl.com/api>
   <api:groups>
        <entry> 
            <key>Affiliate</key>
            <value>
                <apilisting>
                    <entry>
                        <key>value</key>
                            <value>
                                <get>https://url1.com</get>
                            </value>
                    </entry>
                </apilisting>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </api>
</ns2>
```

I want to read get node from the above xml format.there are about 10-12 fragments like above in xml file.So i want to read get node value from all fragments and put them in an array.

I am using simplexmlelement in php for reading xml
Please guide on how to get required node value
lets say i put whole of xml above in variable called data,which i have used below.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

echo $xml->ns2->api:groups->entry->value->apilisting-entry->value->{get};
```

Comment: Share your current code so we can see where the error is, and which node(s) you want to get and store.

Comment: k.i m posting sir...

Comment: please check now sir...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24101080/2265374

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code.

```
echo $xml->ns2->api:groups->entry->value->apilisting-entry->value->{get};
```

should be:

```
echo $xml->ns2->api:groups->entry->value->apilisting->entry->value->{get};
```

Note the `->` after `apilisting`

And be aware of the :groups namespacing in your xml example.

Comment: Sorry about the typo,but still i m not able to print the required node.is it because of colon in node handling???

Comment: `</api>` shoud be `</api:groups>`. Also the namespace in your xml document has to be defined.

Comment: getting syntax error when trying to add colon to node in php statement and i m reading this xml from an api with curl,so that xml is having namespace there..

Answer (score 0):

To make PHP understand you have to give typecasting forcefully on object like below:

```
$array = (array) $xml->ns2->api:groups->entry->value->apilisting->entry->value->get; 

print_r($array);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array ([0] => 'https://url1.com')
```