# Can't get out namespace attributes of XML

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml

Trying to get out the value from `<af:location>value</af:location>`. First of all; Yes, I have searched **a lot** for answers of how to do. Read a lot of questions here on Stackoverflow and tried many codes. But just can't get it to work.

I can't show all attempts I have did, cause I don't remember all things I tried.

Here is a stripped version of the code I'm using:

```
$xml_dump = Feed::curl_file_get_contents($url);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    if ($xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_dump))
    {

    }
```

I have for example tried:

- The namespace parameter `'af'` in -> `simplexml_load_string($xml_dump, null, 0, 'af', true)`
- `$xml->getNamespaces(true)`
- `$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_dump); $namespaces = $sxe->getNamespaces(true);`

But none of them works.

The `$xml_dump` contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:af="http://www.example.se/rss">
    <channel>
        <title>RSS Title - Example.se</title>
        <link>http://www.example.se</link>
        <description>A description of the site</description>
        <pubDate>Wed, 24 Feb 2016 12:20:03 +0100</pubDate>


                <item>
                     <title>The title</title>
                     <link>http://www.example.se/2.1799db44et3a9800024.html?id=233068</link>
                     <description>A lot of text. A lot of text. A lot of text.</description>
                     <guid isPermaLink="false">example.se:item:233068</guid>

                     <pubDate>Wed, 24 Feb 2016 14:55:34 +0100</pubDate>
                     <af:profession>16/5311/5716</af:profession>
                     <af:location>1/160</af:location>

                </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**SOLVED!**

And the answer is:

```
$loc = $item->xpath('af:location');
echo $loc[0];
```

Comment: You should always register your own prefixes for Xpath. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24101080/2265374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear, I have to say. You mentioned about getting value from an element with prefix at the beginning of the question. But seems to try to get a namespace instead in every attempted codes.

> *"Trying to get out the value from `<af:location>value</af:location>`"*

If you mean to get the value from the element mentioned above, then this is one possible way :

```
$location = $xml->xpath('//af:location')[0];
echo $location;
```

**output :**

```
1/160
```

---

If you mean to get the namespace URI by prefix name instead, then using `getNamespaces()` is the way to go :

```
echo $xml->getNamespaces(true)['af'];
```

**output :**

```
http://www.example.se/rss
```

Comment: Aha, then I have misunderstood a lot. And now been learned something. It's however the first of your examples I wanted. Question: The array, is that an array of all `<af:location>` in the whole feed. Or can I take the first / [0] from every `$item->xpath('//af:location')`? Do you understand how I mean?

Comment: I think you'll need to add a dot at the beginning to make the XPath relative to current `$item` : `$item->xpath('.//af:location')`. As for direct child, you can omit the `//` part : `$item->xpath('af:location')` too

Answer (score 0):

We really need a decent canonical answer for this, but I'm going to repeat it again here, since you searched and didn't find. The answer is really very simple: you use [the `children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).

This takes either the URI which permanently identifies the namespace (recommended) or the prefix used in the particular document you're parsing (might be subject to change if the file is auto-generated).

In your example, we have `xmlns:af="http://www.example.se/rss"`, so we could save that URI to a constant to identify the namespace with something meaningful to us:

```
define('XMLNS_RSSAF', 'http://www.example.se/rss');
```

Then when parsing the XML, you traverse to the `item` element in the normal way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_dump);
foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $item ) {
    // ...
}
```

And you get to the namespaced children of `$item` by specifying the namespace:

```
$location = (string) $item->children(XMLNS_RSSAF)->location;
```